# How can i automate Flutter Mobile Application

Tags: flutter, automation, flutter-test

The development of our Mobile App is in Flutter framework using Dart language.

We are trying to Automate the Mobile App using Appium-web driver with the .apk/.ipa file. We don't want to use Flutter framework for automation. That is the purpose, we are trying to automate using Appium web-driver/Appium flutter driver.
But our team is facing few challenges in performing the Automation using Appium-web driver, we are looking for someone who can guide/help us.

Is there any solution that my Automation team can do automate using Appium-web driver?

Thanks & Regards,
Swetha

Comment: Have you tried using Firebase Test Lab ? It is one of free Firebase services